# Markers, Info windows and automatically zooms to fit all markers in

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been trying to create a google map that has clickable markers and the zoom level adapts to the amount of markers on the map, I have the following code which I know is not quite right, but can't figure out why, any pointers as to where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {

  // My options
  var myOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }

  // Create map on #map_canva
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  // Define boundarys
  var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // Create array
  var countries = [
      {title:'Theatre by the Lake', lat:54.32223562211788, lon:-2.742498400000045, content:"<h2>Theatre by the Lake</h2>"},
      {title:'Pirelli International Rally',  content:"<h2>Pirelli International Rally</h2>"},
      {title:'Lowther Castle',  content:"<h2>Lowther Castle</h2>"},
      {title:'South Lakes Wild Animal Park',  content:"<h2>South Lakes Wild Animal Park</h2>"},
      {title:'Cumbria Karting',  content:"<h2>Cumbria Karting</h2>"},
  ];

  // Create markers
  for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) { 
      var c = countries[i]; 
      c.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(c.lat, c.lon), 
          map: map,
          icon: '/display_images/icon_stockist.png',
          title: c.title});
      c.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: c.content}); 
      google.maps.event.addListener(c.marker, 'click', makeCallback(c)); 
      // Create marker bounds
      markerBounds.extend(countries);
  } 

  // Create info windows based on above content
  function makeCallback(country) { 
      return function () { 
          country.infowindow.open(map, country.marker); 
      }; 
  }
}

// Fit map to marker boundaries
map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
</script>
```

Comment: There's no need to add tags to your title, there's a tag system for that. For more information and the discussion of this, please refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you create map as a local variable in your initialize function, then you try to access it outwith that function when you call `map.fitBounds`, which hasn't got access to it.

Either declare map outwith of `initialize`, or move the map.fitBounds() within your initialize function.

Also when you call `markerBounds.extend(countries);`, you're passing it your entire countries array, when what you really need is to pass it a single LatLng object.  Try something like this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) { 
      var c = countries[i]; 
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(c.lat, c.lon);
      c.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng, 
          map: map,
          icon: '/display_images/icon_stockist.png',
          title: c.title});
      c.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: c.content}); 
      google.maps.event.addListener(c.marker, 'click', makeCallback(c)); 
      // Create marker bounds
      markerBounds.extend(latlng);
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to call the map.fitBounds(bounds) right after the loop runs as well (rather than outside of the initialize function, before the bounds has been extended with the positions of all the markers).

Comment: Thanks guys, will give it a go now!